# Google Maps control to move accordingly

Tags: css, google-maps

Basically, I just want to copy http://maps.google.com.
I'd like to use google maps on 'full screen' and have a floating menu that can slide in and out. 
However, when it's slided out, the zoom controls should 'move accordingly' and not get hidden behind the menu.

Edit, to clarify:
I want Google Maps to be 100% by 100%, have that working. I also want to have a menu overlay in the top left corner (or just the whole left side) with the ability to slide in and out.
However, on the left top side, there's the Google Maps zoom control, I don't want my menu to cover it, I want it to 'scoot' over when my menu is open.

Google do this as well on their webbased version: http://maps.googl.com

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Do you want to implement something *like* Google Maps? Or do you want to embed *a* Google map?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create the right HTML set up.
For instance:

**HTML**

```
<div id="main-wrapper">
  <div id="left-menu-wrapper">
     <!-- code with navigation -->
     <a href="javascript:toggleMenu();"> Show / Hide </a>
  </div>
  <div id="google-window-wrapper">
     <!-- code to display google map here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main-wrapper {

}
#left-menu-wrapper{
    width:200px;
    float:left;
}
#google-window-wrapper{
    width:auto;
}
```

**javascript**
( used to toggle the menu block )

```
var windowHidden = false;
function toggleMenu(){
    windowHidden = !windowHidden;
    document.getElementById("left-menu-wrapper").style.width = 
              (windowHidden) ? "0px" : "200px";
}
```

Is this sort of what you are looking for ?

Comment: I think you have a wrong idea about the 100%, Gerben. The way I'm suggesting my HTML layout *should* work for your needs. The menu at the Google Maps website does not go **over** the map, it **moves** the google map.

Comment: I want the map itself to be static, I just want this one Zoom-controller element to move.

Comment: on the Google Maps website it only moves the map if the feature clicked on would be underneath the sidebar when it slides out, also it works differently on mobile